# White window when debugging Electron forge "typescript + webpack" app from VSCode - MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY variable is not being set

Tags: visual-studio-code, webpack, electron, vscode-debugger, electron-forge

I created an Electron forge project as described in [the forge guide](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template) using the "typescript + webpack" template:

```
> yarn create electron-app debugging-test --template=typescript-webpack
```

The generated app works fine when running `npm start`. Then I wanted to configure VSCode debugger for this template so I followed [the debugging section of the forge guide](https://www.electronforge.io/advanced/debugging) and created `launch.json` file with this content:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Electron Main",
  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron-forge-vscode-nix",
  "windows": {
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron-forge-vscode-win.cmd"
  },
  // runtimeArgs will be passed directly to your Electron application
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ],
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

This does not really work for me. After clicking `F5` the debugger starts but it doesn't break on any breakpoints in the main process nor no window appears. Then I tried the `launch.json` from [Microsoft's vscode-recipes](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Electron):

```
{
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
          {
              "type": "node",
              "request": "launch",
              "name": "Electron: Main",
              "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
              "runtimeArgs": [
                  "--remote-debugging-port=9223",
                  "."
              ],
              "windows": {
                  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
              }
          },
          {
              "name": "Electron: Renderer",
              "type": "chrome",
              "request": "attach",
              "port": 9223,
              "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
              "timeout": 30000
          }
      ],
      "compounds": [
          {
              "name": "Electron: All",
              "configurations": [
                  "Electron: Main",
                  "Electron: Renderer"
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
```

This one, after hitting `F5`, starts the Electron window fine and even breakpoints in the main process are hit but no content is loaded to the window. The window is white. When breaking on line 21 in index.ts:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);
```

I see that the `MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY` variable is not set and that's why there is no content loaded to the window.

What's the correct VSCode setup to debug "typescript + webpack" electron's forge template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this is a bug in Windows that is tracked here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/2681) on Github. The workaround is to remove the `fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin`. E.g., in `webpack.plugins.js` remove the `new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()` from the array for now until it is fixed:

```
//const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = [/*new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()*/];
```

After that debugging both, main and renderer, processes work great!